# Webform Thumbnail Image Not Created

Tags: webforms, files, media

I've created a form using D7 Webform 7.x-3.20. This form works in the following manner:

1. Fill out form and attach image.
2. Email is sent to admin to approve where you click through to admin approval pages.
3. Approve information and upload image (no issue).
4. Page generation page where you select the image to thumbnail.
5. Save and publish page which is added automatically to a gallery.

One issue; on step 4 the thumbnail will occasionally break and not generate in the specified folder I've defined after so large a size. I've tested to confirm it's not a file type since all JPG, GIF and PNG work just fine. It is only after about 10MB of size the issue presents itself. I've also checked my form to confirm it allows for larger file uploads than that. Additionally my php.ini file is currently allowing for up to 150 MB file size during this time of testing.

Hopefully we can brainstorm this issue together and come up with a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A 10MB image might need a lot of CPU and RAM to resize.
What are your settings for `memory_limit` or maybe `max_execution_time`? Maybe try to increase them for testing.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please ask an explicit question. So far, you simply stated facts.

Comment: Hi Kiamlaluno, sorry if I didn't come across clearly as to what I was trying to troubleshoot. My express interest is in solving why the thumbnail made in number 4 of the list above doesn't always generate.

Comment: @Chris   php_value max_execution_time              60
  php_value memory_limit                    128M

Comment: @Chris I've tested this to the point where I've pushed those settings far beyond the time and limit listed in the comment above. Additionally, I've also been able to have the thumbnail not generate at a much lower file size – 4mb. Any additional thoughts?

Additionally the file they are located in has a permissions level of 775

Comment: I just tried it as well but that seems to be fine. Did you try another server? Maybe it's not so much  a Drupal issue but rather a combination of Drupal and Server or similar? I can't really reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have not tried this myself, but I think that may be where my issue is taking me next from the research that I've done to this point. I'll try and reproduce similar results on a separate server instance, and if I continue to have the same results issues I'll be sure to double back here with my findings or my success.

Comment: Sadly, after some time with this the new server update didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Update: So it seems the images are failing apparently due to a max-width. The images that are failing are a particularly large size in one way or another. 4000px wide. Once the image size is reduced and resaved the file works correctly without issue.

Thoughts in regards to how to remove this restriction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. This was a combination of issues with file compression, max width dimensions and ram allocated to it.